# Suppose we have a rvalue reference, is the rvalue persistent?

Tags: c++

Here is a example using `boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr` to infer the type of a variable.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <cstdio>


#define PRINT_TYPE(x) std::cout << "type of " #x " is "  << \
    boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(x)>().pretty_name() << std::endl


int main(){
    int x = 1;

    int&& w = std::move(1);
    printf("w=%x\n",w);

    PRINT_TYPE(x);
    printf("w=%x\n",w);

    return 0;
}
```

However, it is confusing that the output shows that the rvalue `1`referred by `w` is modified.

```
$ g++ b.cpp -o b.out; ./b.out
w=1
type of x is int
w=ca04a90
```

I have checked the assembly and it shows that the statement `PRINT_TYPE(x)` actually modified the content of memory which belongs to the rvalue `1`.

```
 int&& w = std::move(1);
    1d99:       c7 45 b0 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x50(%rbp)       # <- **-0x50(%rbp) is the address of rvalue 1**
    1da0:       48 8d 45 b0             lea    -0x50(%rbp),%rax
    1da4:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
    1da7:       e8 34 06 00 00          callq  23e0 <_ZSt4moveIiEONSt16remove_referenceIT_E4typeEOS1_>
    1dac:       48 89 45 b8             mov    %rax,-0x48(%rbp)

...

    PRINT_TYPE(x);
    1dc9:   48 8d 35 64 12 00 00    lea    0x1264(%rip),%rsi        # 3034 <_ZStL6ignore+0x23>
    1dd0:   48 8d 3d 49 32 20 00    lea    0x203249(%rip),%rdi        # 205020 <_ZSt4cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4>
    1dd7:   e8 24 fd ff ff          callq  1b00 <_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@plt>
    1ddc:   48 89 c3                mov    %rax,%rbx
    1ddf:   e8 5e 09 00 00          callq  2742 <_ZN5boost9typeindex16type_id_with_cvrIiEENS0_14stl_type_indexEv>
    1de4:   48 89 45 b0             mov    %rax,-0x50(%rbp)           # <- **-0x50(%rbp) is modified**
    1de8:   48 8d 45 c0             lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rax
    1dec:   48 8d 55 b0             lea    -0x50(%rbp),%rdx
    1df0:   48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
    1df3:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
    1df6:   e8 13 04 00 00          callq  220e <_ZNK5boost9typeindex14stl_type_index11pretty_nameB5cxx11Ev>
    1dfb:   48 8d 45 c0             lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rax
    1dff:   48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
    1e02:   48 89 df                mov    %rbx,%rdi
    1e05:   e8 e6 fc ff ff          callq  1af0 <_ZStlsIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES7_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS4_S5_T1_EE@plt>
    1e0a:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
    1e0d:   48 8b 05 bc 31 20 00    mov    0x2031bc(%rip),%rax        # 204fd0 <_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_@GLIBCXX_3.4>
    1e14:   48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
    1e17:   48 89 d7                mov    %rdx,%rdi
    1e1a:   e8 21 fd ff ff          callq  1b40 <_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E@plt>
    1e1f:   48 8d 45 c0             lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rax
    1e23:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
    1e26:   e8 45 fc ff ff          callq  1a70 <_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev@plt>
```

How could I explain this phenomenon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`w` refers to a temporary stack object (the first two lines of the disassembly).  The life of the temporary ends at the end of the statement.  This leaves `w` as a dangling reference.  This same memory address is reused later (see the line labeled `1de4` in the disassembly), overwriting the `1` that was stored there.

Answer (score 0):

Another phenomenon is that when we use *auto type inference*, which will ignore all the references,  value copying actually happens.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <cstdio>


#define PRINT_TYPE(x) std::cout << "type of " #x " is "  << \
    boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(x)>().pretty_name() << std::endl


int main(){
    int x = 1;
    int *y = &x;

    auto w = std::move(1);
    printf("w=%x\n",w);

    PRINT_TYPE(x);
    printf("w=%x\n",w);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
w=1
type of x is int
w=1
```

Answer (score 0):

`int&& w = 1;` will extends lifetime of temporary.

`std::move` return a rvalue reference, and so, no life time extension happens with

`int&& w = std::move(1);`

`w` is dangling at end of statement. And so accessing it is UB.